# Is it possible to have multiple PWA's on a single website?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

Is it possible to have multiple PWA's on a single website? My website has certain subpages like this:

- www.example.com/Page1
- www.example.com/Page2

Now I want a PWA for "Page1" and a different PWA for "Page2". So if you go to Page1 you will get an add to home screen popup and if you go to Page2 you will get the add to home screen popup. So you have two different PWA's on your home screen.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - this should work. You would need a separate manifest.json and service worker for each page. Please try it and let us know if you are successful.